# How can I load a propertylist from a file in common lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a text file containing a list of property lists.  The content looks like the following.  How can I load it into a property list?

```
((:NOMBREMATERIA "LENGUAJES DE PROGRAMACIÓN" :IDMATERIA   "FIEC01552"
  :CLASES NIL :NOTAPROYECTOS NIL   :HORASSEMESTRE "40" :NOTAEXAMENES NIL 
  :NOTATAREAS NIL   :CONTRIBUCION_TAREAS 0.1 :CONTRIBUCION_NOTAPROYECTO 0.5   
  :CONTRIBUCION_NOTAEXAMEN 0.4)
 (:NOMBREMATERIA "HERRAMIENTAS DE COLABORACION DIGITAL" :IDMATERIA "FIEC06460"
  :CLASES NIL :NOTAPROYECTOS NIL   :HORASSEMESTRE "40" :NOTAEXAMENES NIL
  :NOTATAREAS NIL   :CONTRIBUCION_TAREAS 0.1 :CONTRIBUCION_NOTAPROYECTO 0.5
  :CONTRIBUCION_NOTAEXAMEN 0.4))
```

Comment: The content you're showing us is actually a *list* of property lists, not a single property list. Are you trying to read in a list of property lists, or just one of the lists that's there?

Comment: I already figured it out how to read it, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file and read in the data:

```
(with-open-file (f "file.txt")
  (read f))
```

Comment: You usually should bind `*read-eval*` to `nil` when using `read` on external input.  Otherwise, an attacker can inject things through the `#.`(http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhf.htm) reader macro.